# Search and filter with custom field in taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

I have created additional fields for myself in taxonomy. Now I would like to do a search using the values entered into them. I have a problem with this. What is wrong here and how should it be?

I'd like to filter by this "state" value.

[image]

```
$args = array(
    // 's' => $searchText,
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'     => 'cars',

    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation'        => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'car-localization',
            'field'    =>  'slug',
            'terms'     => array('localization-2'),
        )
    ),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'        => 'AND',
        
        array(
            'key'        => 'car_name',
            'value'        => $carName,
            'compare'    => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => 'car_year',
            'value'        => $carYear,
            'compare'    => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you tried to narrow down by removing pieces of your posted custom query? Have you check the database to ensure the keys are the same?

Comment: Yes. I would like it to search me those posts that have the value "testvalue" in the state field in taxonomy

Comment: Assuming all your keys and variables exist - the WP_Query appears correct. Maybe try to simplify your issue and narrow down exactly where the query fails by removing parts of the query until it starts working. Then add parts in, piece by piece until you find exactly where it breaks and [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/410296/edit) with more information.

Comment: you're trying to find all the posts ( A ) that have a term in taxonomy ( B ) but only the terms that have a specific term meta? That is going to be wildly expensive/slow, and impossible on most shared hosts. This cannot be done with `meta_query` and `WP_Query`, and requires multiple function calls. You would need to separately figure out which terms have the meta, then use those term IDs in a `tax_query`. **Structuring your sites data like this is a major mistake,** and will cripple your sites performance and ability to scale with traffic

Comment: If the goal as I suspect is to store localised names for each term then allow users to search by those localised versions then the only way this will work is either with separate terms, or dedicated search software such as ElasticSearch or Solr. The cost of doing what you're asking without this will be massive, expect doing this to take 10-30+ seconds for any small-medium sized site, with that number growing rapidly as the number of terms/localisations increases